# How to integrate Balloonpanel plugin into my editor?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I try to integrate balloonpanel plugin to my editor.

I use the code from the docs.

```
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
 var toolbar = new CKEDITOR.ui.balloonToolbar( editor );

 toolbar.addItems( {
    link: new CKEDITOR.ui.button( {
        command: 'link'
    } ),
    unlink: new CKEDITOR.ui.button( {
        command: 'unlink'
    } )
 } );

 editor.on( 'selectionChange', function( evt ) {
    var lastElement = evt.data.path.lastElement;

    if ( lastElement ) {
        toolbar.attach( lastElement );
    }
 } );
} );
```

But, when I click on the editor it will give the below error message.

[image: Error Message]

And the doc link is provided below

[Balloonpanel Docs Link](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_ui_balloonToolbar.html)

I don't know what it means.

**Update:(Attache code)**

My Original code Looks like this,

```
<body>
    <textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
    <script>
        CKEDITOR.replace('editor1', {
        toolbarGroups: [{
            name: 'basicstyles'
        }, {
            name: 'authorgroup'
        }],
        removePlugins: 'indent,indentblock,indentlist,list,removeformat,table,tabletools,entities,menu,find,font,iframe,pagebreak,flash,print,preview,save,smiley,pastetext,crossreference,youtube,footnotes,dragdrop,basket,horizontalrule,indentlist,image,format,selectall,specialchar,spellchecker,pastefromword,showblocks,link,unlink,anchor,copyformatting',
        extraPlugins: 'indentmodify,indentblockmodify,indentlistmodify,listmodify,removeformatmodified,table1,tabletools1,entitiesmodified,menumodified,findmodified,stylesheetparser,characterStyle,zoom,eventhandler,navigate,comment,symbol,notification,authorproff,proffpara,Newcitation,customfootnotes,floatingmenu,pubsearch,balloontoolbar,balloonpanel,autocorrect' 
        });    


        //My instanceReady Code Goes Here

        </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked this code sample with fresh CKEditor instance and it works fine. You are giving us too little information to get any solid answer.

To run this sample without errors or odd behavior you should include `wysiwygarea,toolbar,link,balloontoolbar` plugins to your CKEditor configuration. Visit [Setting CKEditor configuration](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_configuration.html) if you need some help with it.

If it doesn't solve your problem show us some code or try to reproduce the issue with minimal configuration.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/jacekbogdanski/pen/KomewQ) working sample.

I have to mention that it could not work as expected because we have some issue with `balloonpanel` positioning for a selection. You can find more information about actual status of the issue on [github](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/issues/1176)

Comment: Could you please give me any working example on jsfiddle or any other website?